# quality problem with html2canvas and jscharts

Tags: html2canvas

I have been searching and testing for hours and cant seem to find a solution. I need to convert a html div with a jschart to an image. I am using the below code to create the image but the quality is very low. I am using version 0.4.1, for some reason the newest version of html2canvas is not working..

Anybody found a solution to this?

```
function saveAsImage() {

var $wrapper = $("#ReportContainer");

html2canvas($wrapper, {

onrendered: function(canvas) {

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
link.download = 'myChart.jpeg';
link.click();

}
});

}
```

Comment: play with the `scale` option (value 3 will be high quality) https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/

Comment: yes tried that , but this doesnt help with the resolution.